# UWP Unable to activate windows store app error: the app didn't start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am asking this question - and I know that there are multiple ones here in StackOverflow and other sites - because I have tried everything out there but no solution.

My problem is that this error that appears whenever I try to start the UWP app:
[image]

- I tried switching between platforms (x64 and x86)
- I tried to clean the solution and rebuild
- I made sure that the project was on the C drive

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Are you in a corporate domain? Sometimes there are security policies that prohibit store apps or only allow apps signed by defined publishers. Perhaps there is additional error information in the eventlog

Comment: I have run into the same error and the cause of my case is the certificate used to build the app has expired.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the target version to latest version ?

Comment: The UWP startup process appears to be hiding the underlying reason that prevents the app from starting in the first place. If you locate where the app is deployed and launch .exe directly there is a good chance you will get an actual useful error message describing what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem for a while. People suggest a lot of random workarounds (clean the project, move the project folder, repair/reinstall Visual Studio, delete configuration files, and so on).

[This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47051/vs-2017-pro-will-not-launch-a-uwp-app-in-debug-mod.html) is the most sensible solution I've found, and the one that worked for me.
Basically, just open the Project properties, Build tab and make sure the option "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" is checked.

[image]